# Change variable type mysql with existing data

Tags: mysql, variables

Hi I've got a variable 'text' within my MYSQL database that gathers something like a status update. I believe this variable has a limit of 200?

- Is this something that is already set?
- If so what variable would be
  suitable for both a quick 150 character updates as well as something
  as long as a 1500 word article if a user wanted to elaborate?
- How do
  i change it within phpmyadmin to the desired new variable if data is
  currently present within the present form?

Comment: HeidiSQL is much better than phpmyadmin.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply Richard. I've never heard of HeidiSQL, but I'll look inot that. For now I'm using what is there in phpMyadmin. I think I can clarify a bit more with the question of what is the difference between TEXT LONGTEXT ect. Whic hwould be suitable for both and how many characters is roughly a 1500 word article. Is it each letter and space? Of course the main issue is how would I change this within phpMyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-type-overview.html

VARCHAR

> A variable-length string. M represents the maximum column length in
>   characters. The range of M is 0 to 65,535.

TEXT

> A TEXT column with a maximum length of 65,535 (216 – 1) characters.

I thinking both VARCHAR(1500) and TEXT(1500) is ok for you.

> How do i change it within phpmyadmin to the desired new variable if
>   data is currently present within the present form?

To change data type of a column, I would just use SQL, this work in any tools.

```
ALTER TABLE  `tablename` CHANGE  `colname` VARCHAR( 1500 );
```

Answer (score 0):

`Change` doesn't work for us, we needed to use `Modify`:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` MODIFY `colname` VARCHAR( 1500 );
```